# having multiple describe in spec leads to weird behaviour

Tags: mocha.js, cypress

I have 2 describe blocks in a spec file.
First, **describe** visits **xyz.com** and Second, **describe** visits **abc.com**

And I need these 2 describe in one spec only. The wired behavior I see is it runs the tests smoothly but after visiting abc.com from 2nd describe it starts running 1st describe again. An infinite loop of tests

```
var signedOutArtifactID = null;

describe('WEB APP E2E tests', function() {
  var token = null;

  before(function() {
    cy.visit('/');

    // Login
    cy.get('#username')
      .type(auth.geneticist.username);

    cy.get('#password')
      .type(auth.geneticist.password);

    cy.get('button')
      .contains('Login')
      .click()
      .should(function() {
        token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        expect(token).not.to.be.null;
      });
  });

  beforeEach(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);

    cy.contains('Logout')
      .should('exist');

    expect(localStorage.getItem('token'));
  });

  it('should land on home page', function() {
    cy.url()
      .should('include', '/home');
  });


  it('should save and generate and end up on signout page', function() {
    cy.contains('Save and Generate Report')
      .click();

    cy.url()
      .should('include', '/sign-out');
  });

  it('should signout and send successfully', function() {
    cy.url()
      .should(function(currentURL) {
        signedOutArtifactID = currentURL.match(/2-([0-9]+)/)[0];
        expect(signedOutArtifactID).not.to.be.null;
    });

    // Make sure interpretation was updated
    cy.get('.card-body pre')
      .should('contain', 'test interpretation added by cypress');

    cy.contains('Sign Out and Send')
      .click();

    cy.contains('Yes, sign out and send')
      .click();

  });


});


describe('2nd WEB APP E2E tests', function() {

  before(function () {
    cy.visit({
      url:`https://webappurl.com/search?scope=All&query=${signedOutArtifactID}`,
      failOnStatusCode: false
    })
  })  

  it('Review Completed step in clarity', async () => {

    cy.get('#username').type(auth.clarity_creds.username)
    cy.get('#password').type(auth.clarity_creds.password)
    cy.get('#sign-in').click()

    cy.get('.result-name').click()
    cy.get('.view-work-link').contains('QWERTYU-IDS').click()

    cy.get('.download-file-link ')
      .should(($downloads) => {
        expect($downloads).to.have.length(2)
      })

  });

});
```

Comment: See: [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without code it's very difficult to help you.

Comment: @alfasin wasn't sure if code snippet will help,  but I have updated the question

Comment: Why are two different describes in the root of the same file? if they're not related please put them in separate files. If they _are_ related put them both nested inside an additional describe and add a string that describes what you're about to test in this file. WDYT?

Comment: @alfasin I tried putting them in separate files also tried having 2 describes inside one but it didn't work(faced the same issue). I need signedOutArtifactID generated in `should signout and send successfully` test. both describes are hitting different webapps

Comment: If you put them in different files - how come both of them got called?

Comment: @alfasin I cannot put them in different files as I'm sharing a variable between two describes. Even If I dont share anything having 2 describes(with different url) is running all tests again and again

Comment: Having them in the same file shouldn't cause any problems - I'm doing it all the time, too.

Answer (score 7):

`describe` defines a test suite. You can only have one top-level test suite per file, and only one domain per test.

I would just change your `describe`s to `context`s and wrap both `context`s in a single `describe`, like so:

```js
var signedOutArtifactID = null;

describe('e2e tests', function() {

  context('WEB APP E2E tests', function() {
    var token = null;

    before(function() {
      cy.visit('/');

      // Login
      cy.get('#username')
        .type(auth.geneticist.username);

      cy.get('#password')
        .type(auth.geneticist.password);

      cy.get('button')
        .contains('Login')
        .click()
        .should(function() {
          token = localStorage.getItem('token');
          expect(token).not.to.be.null;
        });
    });

    beforeEach(function() {
      localStorage.setItem('token', token);

      cy.contains('Logout')
        .should('exist');

      expect(localStorage.getItem('token'));
    });

    it('should land on home page', function() {
      cy.url()
        .should('include', '/home');
    });


    it('should save and generate and end up on signout page', function() {
      cy.contains('Save and Generate Report')
        .click();

      cy.url()
        .should('include', '/sign-out');
    });

    it('should signout and send successfully', function() {
      cy.url()
        .should(function(currentURL) {
          signedOutArtifactID = currentURL.match(/2-([0-9]+)/)[0];
          expect(signedOutArtifactID).not.to.be.null;
      });

      // Make sure interpretation was updated
      cy.get('.card-body pre')
        .should('contain', 'test interpretation added by cypress');

      cy.contains('Sign Out and Send')
        .click();

      cy.contains('Yes, sign out and send')
        .click();

    });


  });


  context('2nd WEB APP E2E tests', function() {

    before(function () {
      cy.visit({
        url:`https://webappurl.com/search?scope=All&query=${signedOutArtifactID}`,
        failOnStatusCode: false
      })
    })  

    it('Review Completed step in clarity', async () => {

      cy.get('#username').type(auth.clarity_creds.username)
      cy.get('#password').type(auth.clarity_creds.password)
      cy.get('#sign-in').click()

      cy.get('.result-name').click()
      cy.get('.view-work-link').contains('QWERTYU-IDS').click()

      cy.get('.download-file-link ')
        .should(($downloads) => {
          expect($downloads).to.have.length(2)
        })

    });

  });

})
```

Comment: `context` was just an synonyms or alias for `describe`, and has been removed in recent Jasmine versions.

Answer (score 0):

There should be one `describe` block per `suite` (specification file). Therefore, when I need to wrap multiple related tests in one specification file I use `context`. Also, the following is what cypress documentation says:

> The test interface, borrowed from Mocha, provides describe(),
> context(), it() and specify().
>
> context() is identical to describe() and specify() is identical to
> it(), so choose whatever terminology works best for you

However, I believe the test structure and `describe`, `context`, `it` hierarchy is a little off track. So, here is how I write tests:

```
describe('User Authentication Using Custom Auth Token', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.on('uncaught:exception', err => {
          console.log('cypress has detected uncaught exception', err);
          return false;
        });
      });
    context('when not authenticated', () => {
        it('Redirects to /login and Stays on /Login', () => {
        cy.visit('/');
        cy.location('pathname').should('equal', '/login');
        // more on your logic  
        });
    context('when authenticated', () => {
      it('Successful login using Custom Auth Token', ()=>{
        cy.visit('/')
        cy.login();
        // more on your logic  
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can have more than one describe per file. `describe` and `context` are synonyms and can be used interchangeably.